# div animation not repeating on click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate div from outside the window to inside every time I click on link but it works only one time not again, please help me where I am wrong.

```
<li>
    <a id='ajaxLoad1' onclick='ajaxFunc(event, this);' href="url1">1st content</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id='ajaxLoad2' onclick='ajaxFunc(event, this);' href="url2">2nd content</a>
</li>

<div id='contentDiv' style="background: #98bf21; height: 200px; width: 800px;  position: absolute;"></div>
```

```js
function ajaxFunc(param, thisParam) {
    param.preventDefault();

    var href = $(thisParam).attr('href');
    var position = '100px';

    $('#contentDiv').css('margin-left','-100%');
    $("#contentDiv").animate({right: position});

    $('#contentDiv').load(href);
}
```

Comment: As `#contentDiv` is already on specified position after first click, where will it move ?

Comment: you must have to move firstly `#contentDiv` outside the window where it was before animation and then it will be move next time that what you want

Comment: how can i bring it back on new click

Comment: something like this? [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rc3sLy0w/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#contentDiv').css({
  'right': 'initial',
  'margin-left': '-100%'
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `margin-left` for `right` in your code:

```js
function ajaxFunc(param, thisParam) {
    param.preventDefault();

    var href = $(thisParam).attr('href');
    var position = '100px';

    $('#contentDiv').css('right','100%');
    $("#contentDiv").animate({right: position});
  

    $('#contentDiv').load(href);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <a id='ajaxLoad1' onclick='ajaxFunc(event, this);' href="url1">1st content</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id='ajaxLoad2' onclick='ajaxFunc(event, this);' href="url2">2nd content</a>
</li>

<div id='contentDiv' style="background: #98bf21; height: 200px; width: 800px;  position: absolute;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the trick to reinitialize all style

```
    $('#contentDiv').attr('style','background:#98bf21;height:200px;width:800px;position:absolute;');
$("#contentDiv").animate({left: '0px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the first animation the element has `{'margin-left':'-100%', 'right': '100px'}`.

The element is not reset to its original settings so at the start of the second animation it still has `{'margin-left':'-100%', 'right': '100px'}`.

The simplest solution is for the `.css()` and the `.animate()` directives to address the *same* property, eg `margin-left`. That way, the `.css()` directive will act as a reset for the animation.

```
$('#contentDiv')
    .css('margin-left', '-100%')
    .animate({'margin-left': 0})
    .load($(thisParam).attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

by replacing your `#contentDiv` with the following:

```
<div id='contentDiv' style="background:#98bf21; height:200px;
  width:800px;  position:absolute; "> 
<a href='#' class='closeme'>move me back</a>
  <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

and replacing your `jquery` with the following

```
 $("#ajaxLoad1").click(function(){

    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var position = '100px';

    $('#contentDiv').css('left','100px');
    $("#contentDiv").animate({right: position});

    $('#contentDiv > div').load(href);
    return false;

   })


   $(".closeme").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().css({
            'left' : '-1000px'
        });

   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function ajaxFunc(param, thisParam) {
    param.preventDefault();

    var href = $(thisParam).attr('href');
    var position = '100px';

    // Need to reset
    $('#contentDiv').css({
      'marginLeft': 0,
      'right': 0
    });


    $('#contentDiv').css('margin-left','-100%');
    $("#contentDiv").animate({right: position});

    $('#contentDiv').load(href);
}
```

> Ref: http://jsbin.com/derofu/1/edit?html,js,output